# change font sizes between browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, font-size

I have a menu bar with font size 20px. However the fonts appear larger in some browsers - FF and IE - and smaller in Chrome. 
So far I have been able to find css hacks for IE. However I cannot find a way to make a change to either the Firefox or Chrome.

```
ul#secondary-menu li a strong, ul#secondary-menu > li.logout > a { 
    color:#ffffff;
    display:block;
    font-size:20px;
    font-size:15px\9;
    font-size:15px\0;
    font-size:15px\8;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:-3px; 
}
```

What do I need to add to this CSS to change the size in either Chrome or FF? 
Thanks

Comment: How big is the difference?

Comment: Hi Sebastien, when set to 20px the menu bar is a normal size in chrome but in other browsers appears larger so that the bar spills over onto a second line. It is a dropdown menu so it really makes a difference - and just looks unprofessional. Then if the font size is set smaller to be normal in FF/IE the menu is almost too small to read in chrome. I do not know the difference in ratio of the sizes, if that is what you meant

Comment: Since we can't see it, we can only guess. Are you sure the same font is used? Same line height, letter spacing, word spacing, zoom factor in the browser? And I'm not sure that things like `font-size:15px\8` go down well in all browsers. Tricks like that, that are technically errors, can also be achieved with IE conditional comments. And it may sound silly, but does it make a difference to make the texts uppercase and remove the text-transform?

Comment: Hi Mr Lister, it is a wordpress website re text transform. How would I check the browser issues you mention at the beginning? compare the css settings in each browser?

Comment: No, the CSS will be the same. Check the resulting styles, i.e. the currently used properties. Can you publish something that demonstrates the difference? For instance, I've got [a jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/umDB6/4/) that shows the menu bar is the same height in all browsers.

Comment: CSS hacks :(, people still use those?